# Old 'unknown' versions of applications appearing in Spotlight search results

Tags: spotlight

When I migrated my old Mac to my new one, I copied some applications over from `/Applications` on the old Mac. Some of these were App Store apps, which I of course had to reinstall from the App Store in order to actually run them.

What's happened though, is there are some apps that appear in duplicates, with a white nondescript document icon like so:

[image]

What's going on here? Can I fix this? I've tried reindexing Spotlight both through the GUI exceptions and via Terminal and `scutil`, but to no avail. I've also tried searching "This Mac" for the files, but they don't appear in Finder search results anywhere. The plot also thickens when you compare the created/modified dates of the duplicate to it's proper original: they're always the same.

Comment: A couple of ideas: (1) Do you see the duplicates in System Information.app → Software → Applications?  (2) Does `sudo ls /Applications` reveal anything interesting?

Comment: Also, if you are using Spotlight to back up to a local HD have you excluded that drive from the Spotlight index?

Comment: Nice @Bob - `sudo ls /Applications` showed nothing out of the ordinary, but _some_ of the duplicates do appear in System Information.app → Software → Applications. Catch: not all of them do, e.g. this particular example of Sketch. Thinking this might be a red herring? Most of the paths that appear on the dupes that exist are in `/Downloads`.

Comment: @SteveChambers not the case here.

Comment: @brandonscript Did you mean `/Downloads` or `~/Downloads`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry `~/Downloads`

Comment: Have you tried showing hidden files and going to the location the file says it is? It's possible that the file exists as a ghost file (i.e. It's there but it has no data)

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a cleaning utility (like Onyx) and let it do everything it can, reboot and see what happens. This is **weird.**

Comment: I've tried `ls -as` and nothing hidden appears, and I've tried a cleaning tool. Unfortunately the ghost files don't show a path in the Spotlight results so I don't even know where to look.

Comment: This question is probably too old but I'd be curious if `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user` does anything. This fixes similar problems I run into with duplicate apps in the "Open With" menu. If that doesn't work, the second thing I'd do is try booting into Safe Mode and then back into normal mode. You don't need to actually do anything in Safe Mode, merely booting it causes macOS to clear out a lot of cache stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /Library and do a search for whatever junk you're trying to get rid off. This happened to me for Cisco WebEx where I had 7 versions (most of them junk). Re-creating the index etc won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You have cropped out the bottom portion of that window where it says **Search in Finder**

From there you can select an item and use the path bar to locate it on the filesystem.

You can also use the context menu (control select or right mouse) to **Show in Enclosing Folder** or hood option and **copy the item as Pathname**